# When empty string is allowed FieldEditorPreferencePage is not valid

Tags: java, validation, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing application based on Eclipse RCP.
I created FieldEditorPreferencePage with two field editors. Both editors can have empty page:

```
protected void createFieldEditors() {
    DirectoryFieldEditor pythonDirectoryFieldEditor = new DirectoryFieldEditor(MyPreferenceConstants.PYTHON_DIRECTORY_PATH,
                PreferenceLabelMessages.getString(MyPreferenceConstants.PYTHON_DIRECTORY_PATH),
                getFieldEditorParent());
    pythonDirectoryFieldEditor.setEmptyStringAllowed(true);
    addField(pythonDirectoryFieldEditor);

    DirectoryFieldEditor libraryDirectoryFieldEditor =new DirectoryFieldEditor(MyPreferenceConstants.LIBRARY_DIRECTORY_PATH,
                PreferenceLabelMessages.getString(MyPreferenceConstants.LIBRARY_DIRECTORY_PATH),
                getFieldEditorParent());
    libraryDirectoryFieldEditor.setEmptyStringAllowed(true);
    addField(libraryDirectoryFieldEditor);

}
```

But when I entred valid directory path into one of this fields and another is empty I can't press OK or Apply button because page is not valid. In debug mode I see that empty field return false when `isValid()` method calls. Why the empty field is not valid?
How I can fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Try debugging to see when/if the `refreshValidState` method is being called.

Comment: This method should be call from FieldEditorPreferencePage or FieldEditor?

Comment: It is a method in `StringFieldEditor` which is the super class of `DirectoryFieldEditor`.